# Getting at least 1 red queen after 5 draws from standard deck with replacement

Tags: binomial-distribution

If 5 cards are randomly selected from a standard deck of cards with replacement, what's the probability of getting at least 1 red queen?

Here's what I've done but I'm unsure if it's right, here I'm assuming this is a binomial distribution:

$$Y\sim Bin(52,\frac{1}{26})$$
$$1-P(Y=0)=1-{52\choose 0}*\frac{1}{26}^0*\frac{25}{26}^{52}$$

I'm sure if the number of trials should be $5$ or $52$. Please help me with this. Thank you

Comment: It is not $52$ trials, it is $5$.

Comment: To get insight into the formula, suppose you only drew one card. Clearly the answer in that case is $\frac 2{52}$, yes?  So your formula has to return that value.